# Identity for $\sum\limits_{j = a}^{N}     \binom{N}{j} \binom{j}{a} d^{-j}$?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I have run across the following multinomial series:
$$     \sum_{j = a}^{N}
    \binom{N}{j} \binom{j}{a} d^{-j}
$$
Here, $d>1$. This seems like a formula which has either a well-known identity, or which has no further closed form or simplification. Can anyone shed any light on this formula, or possibly point me to a standard reference?

Comment: for $a=0$ we have $(1+1/d)^N$ (not that this helps)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\sum_{j = a}^{N} \binom{N}{j} \binom{j}{a} d^{-j} = \sum_{j = a}^{N} \binom{N}{a} \binom{N-a}{j-a} d^{-j} = \binom{N}{a} \sum_{j = 0}^{N-a} \binom{N-a}{j} d^{-j-a} $$
$$= d^{-a} \binom{N}{a} \sum_{j = 0}^{N-a} \binom{N-a}{j} d^{-j} =  d^{-a} \binom{N}{a} (1+d^{-1})^{N-a}.$$
The first step uses what's called *trinomial revision*.  See, for example, *Concrete Mathematics*, p. 174.  The last step uses the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use $${N \choose j}{j \choose a} = \frac{ N!}{j! (N-j)!} \frac{j!}{a! (j-a)!} =\frac{N!}{a!(N-a)!} \frac{(N-a)!}{(j-a)! (N-j)!} = {N \choose a}{ N-a \choose j-a}$$ to write your expression as
$${N \choose a} \sum_{j=a}^N { N-a \choose j-a} d^{-j}= {N \choose a} d^{-a} \sum_{j=0}^{N-a} { N -a \choose j} d^{-j} = {N \choose a} d^{-a}  (1+1/d)^{N-a}.$$ (using binomial series)

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned the word "multinomial", here is another way, using the Multinomial theorem.

Expand

$$(1 + x/d + x)^n = \sum_{p+q+r=n} {n \choose p,q,r} 1^p \cdot (x/d)^q \cdot x^r$$

$$= \sum_{a=0}^{n} \sum_{j=a}^{n} {n \choose a,j-a,n-j} 1^{a}  \cdot (x/d)^{j-a} \cdot x^{n-j}$$

$$ = \sum_{a=0}^{n} \left(\sum_{j=a}^{n} {n \choose j} {j \choose a} d^{a-j}\right) x^{n-a}$$

Expand $\displaystyle (1 + x(1+1/d))^n$ using binomial theorem and equate the coefficient of $\displaystyle  x^{n-a}$ on both sides to get

$$ {n \choose a} (1 + 1/d)^{n-a} = \sum_{j=a}^{n} {n \choose j} {j \choose a} d^{a-j}$$

and so

$$ {n \choose a} d^{-a} (1 + 1/d)^{n-a} = \sum_{j=a}^{n} {n \choose j} {j \choose a} d^{-j}$$

Here are a couple more answers which use similar ideas:

[Beautiful identity: $\sum_{k=m}^n (-1)^{k-m} \binom{k}{m} \binom{n}{k} = \delta_{mn}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/beautiful-identity-sum-k-mn-1k-m-binomkm-binomnk-delta/4187#4187)

[Non-probabilistic proofs of a binomial coefficient identity from a probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10346/non-probabilistic-proofs-of-a-binomial-coefficient-identity-from-a-probability-qu/10605#10605)

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** $$\binom{N}{a} d^{-a}(1+d^{-1})^{N-a} \; .$$

I'll leave it up to you to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{j=a}^N {N\choose j}{j\choose a} d^{-j}.$$

Start from
$${j\choose a}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{a+1}} (1+z)^j \; dz.$$

Note that with $j$ and $a$ integers when $j\lt a$ then $j-a \lt 0$ and
$j-(a+1) \lt  -1$ so we may extend  the sum to start  at $j=0$ because
the extra contribution is zero.

This gives for the sum the integral
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{a+1}} 
\sum_{j=0}^N {n\choose j} \times (1+z)^j \times d^{-j} \; dz.$$

This simplifies to
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{a+1}} 
\left(\frac{1+z}{d}+1\right)^N \; dz$$
which is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{a+1}} 
\left(\frac{1+d+z}{d}\right)^N \; dz.$$

Hence the closed form is
$$[z^a] \left(\frac{1+d+z}{d}\right)^N
= \frac{1}{d^N} [z^a] (1+d+z)^N
= \frac{1}{d^N} {N\choose a} (1+d)^{N-a}$$

This finally yields
$$\frac{1}{d^a} \frac{1}{d^{N-a}} {N\choose a} (1+d)^{N-a}
= \frac{1}{d^a} {N\choose a} 
\left(1 + \frac{1}{d}\right)^{N-a}.$$

A trace as to when this method appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/).

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see your answer before I wrote my answer. Thanks.